# Unable to upload Angular2 application gh-pages

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I am getting this

[image: [error]]

I have a website live on my another host and its working perfectly fine. But i will like to upload on `github pages` too. For testing and other reasons. But when i uploaded my angular2 webapp, I got the above error. Do we have to any special setting to do for pages?

Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Smit Shah</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="Smit Shah">
      <link rel="icon" href="app/img/smitico.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gruppo" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
 <body class="indexStyle">
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "smit-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.2",
    "angular2-bootstrap-confirm": "^1.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

I have tried providing more information. If there anything else let me know. Thanks.

And here it the github pages url.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, you need to make sure you have all the files that means no gitignore. Or remove below items from the gitignore.

  1. node_modules
  2. *.js
  3. **.map.js
     4.. And anything related.

Because while deploying on `gh-pages` it doesnt install any npm packages for you.

Secondly,
By default Jekyll does not build node_modules folders, so you'll need to add an empty file named `.nojekyll` to the root of your repository to skip that build. That will include the node_modules folder in future builds.

DONE! It should be working as perfect as it was in local setup.

**Update**
For pathLocationStrategy user:

Change

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="/<app-name>/">
```

*app-name is the repository name

Comment: I am having the same issue. I did what you explain but it doesn't work for me. Any idea? https://github.com/phuwin/yugioh-thecardgame/tree/gh-pages

Comment: @PhuNguyen I dont see `.nojekyll`

Comment: Hi, I have fixed my issue. The problem was because my base-href was "/" and I am using the pathLocationStrategy in my project.

Comment: @PhuNguyen Thanks for the input, i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed my agular2 example app to github gh-pages 
Here try to follow these steps.

1. Delete your gh-pages branch on git.

   ```
    git branch -D gh-pages
   ```
2. Install this angular-cli dependency to your project

   ```
    npm install --save   @angular/cli
   ```
3. Build your project for deploy

   ```
    ng build --prod--aot --base-href "https://<username>.github.io/<repo-name>/"
   ```
4. If you have problem when compiling replace this code in app.module.ts file

   ```
    "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
   ```

   To

   ```
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
              "environments": {
                      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
               }
   ```
5. After successful compiled(100%) just run this command to deploy to gh-pahes

   ```
         ngh --message "Deploy gh pages"
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Aruna I will surly try it out.